# Is it possible to monitor file move event(move file from a folder to another) on Windows?

Tags: windows, events, file, system, monitor

I would like to know how to capture the file move event on Windows.
An event of Moving a folder/file to another location.

I tried JNotify. It supports renamed, modified, deleted,created events, but not moved event.

I remember that on Windows (XP/Vista/7, may be NTFS) provide a service or something like that, which support the moved event.

Does anyone know the name of the service/tool/library name or suggest a solution/workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try filesystemwatcher?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

i've done a tool using this - maybee it helps you with a workaround
https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/109583811292415142803/109583811292415142803/